# T-SQL like operator in conditional

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to do the following (works in MySQL, etc.) in T-SQL:

```sql
    IF(name LIKE '%Amazon%', TRUE, FALSE) AS 'is_amazon'
```

So I tried this, but it errors on the `LIKE` operator:

```sql
   IIF(name LIKE '%Amazon%', 1, 0) AS 'is_amazon'
```

The error is:

> Parse error at line: 25, column: 17: Incorrect syntax near 'LIKE'.

Column 17 in the real world usage is the `L` in `LIKE` for what it's worth.

The Microsoft T-SQL documentation says that:

> `LIKE` is a "logical operator" returning a boolean

so why does this not work?  How can I make this work in T-SQL?

Server version:  Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.15669.0 Jul 14 2022 22:08:00

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type, so true and false don't work. You can use 0/1 to return a BIT datatype which is the closest SQL Server has.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Will correct the example so as to not detract from the basic problem with the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: @DaleK Like I often say: SQL Server does have a boolean type, you just can't select it, or declare a variable or column of that type. It's used all over the place in places like `WHERE` and `CASE`, there are many errors which reference it, the docs reference it, the query plans have it, it's just not usable externally. How annoying...

Comment: @Charlieface agreed, although probably simpler for people less experienced to just think of it as not having a boolean type.

Comment: Your edited question is not reproducible, [its working here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60193195d6ca96ed9873d0231de56dcb)

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? `select @@version` Is it 2008?

Comment: `select @@version`:  `Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.15669.0 Jul 14 2022 22:08:00 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation`

Comment: Shows why you should always add your version number to the question.

Comment: Good advice.  My bad.  Usually I include version numbers in my question.

Comment: Aside: Your code will cheerfully report that `'Shipped to the Llamazone'` is Amazon. A common technique to get "better" results is to add spaces, e.g. `' ' + name + ' ' like '% Amazon %'` to ensure that there is a space or either end of the string bounding the target substring. That doesn't handle parsing the string apart into words, so it will still get tripped up by punctuation marks, e.g. `'Amazon, Inc.'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options.  You can cast as BIT if desired

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('Some Name')
,('Some Amazon Vendor')


Select SomeCol
      ,IsAmazon1 = sign(charindex('Amazon',SomeCol))
      ,IsAmazon2 = case when SomeCol like '%Amazon%' then 1 else 0 end
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol             IsAmazon1   IsAmazon2
Some Name           0           0
Some Amazon Vendor  1           1
```

Comment: It looks like this bit is all I needed: `case when SomeCol like '%Amazon%' then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: `IIF` works perfectly also e.g. `IIF([Name] LIKE '%Amazon%', 1, 0) AS is_amazon`.

Comment: @DaleK Very, very  true.   Failure on my part to include

Comment: Which makes the question unreproducible :(

Comment: See comments on question above.  Maybe it's an Azure SQL Data Warehouse oddity?

Comment: @CXJ did you check the docs for supported versions?

Comment: Seems to say it applies to the database engine I'm using:
```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  
  
match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
```

Comment: But is IIF supported there? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql